# How do I sum all entries that match a lookup table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a column of numbers I want to sum. Each number is associated with a value on a lookup table. I need to find what values I want to use to sum based on the lookup table itself.

[image]

Basically, I need to sum everything in column I based on whether the entry in column J matches a MFG in column M that matches a reference number in column O. I have tried multiple iterations of SumProduct and array formulas, and have had no luck getting it to work. Everything I've read online about summing based on multiple criteria only works if you know ahead of time how many conditions you have to match; I don't have that information.

Comment: How does O play into it?  Does `a` match `A`?  is M17 the answer you expect?  Can you show the math in long hand what you expect eg `1807.30+1124.81+...=???`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm going to pass the formula a variable (row number in the finished sheet). I want it to give me the sum of every MFG that matches that ref number in `O`. In the above, the expected result given `23` as the ref is `1807.30+1124.81+100=3032.11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterated through the second table and if the Ref Num match the input in M16 then it returns the SUMIF() value of MFG from the first table and sums them all together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((M16=$O$7:$O$12)*SUMIF(J:J,$M$7:$M$12,I:I))
```

Notice that the references to Table 2 are limited to the actual data, while the references to table 1 can be full column references.  That has to do with how the formula will iterate.  As it literally will iterate through the second table we want to limit the number of iterations to the data set itself.  While the SUMIF() formula is already optimized and has no detriment to full column references.

[image]